# Can the same individual from a population be chosen in a genetic algorithm?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithms

One population contains 10 individuals, from these 10, 8 are picked based on a selection mechanism. Let's say they are picked using the rank based selection mechanism (so the best ranked has a higher probability of being picked). My question is, when an individual is picked for recombination to create a new generation, is he left out the following picks or not and why?

Comment: If you mean whether the exact same individual can be kept or not in the next population then the answer is yes. There is concept called **elitism** in genetic algorithms where top few individuals are kept unchanged in the next generation.

Comment: That is nice to know, but not what I wanted to know. After the individuals are chosen they are recombined into new individuals. Let's say the bitstring 1000 is very good and has a high chance of being chosen. Could it be that two parents are 1000 and 1000 (so two times the same parent).